# How to restrict awk to only search items contained inside a certain HTML tag?

Tags: awk, replace

I have an AWK script like this, which I will run on a file:

```
cat input.txt | awk 'gsub(/[^ ]*(fish|shark|whale)[^ ]*/,"(&)")' >> output.txt
```

This adds parenthesis to all lines containing the words "fish", "shark", or "whale", for e.g.:

```
The whale asked the shark to swim elsewhere.
The fish were unhappy.
```

After running it through the script, the file becomes:

```
The (whale) asked the (shark) to swim elsewhere.
The (fish) were unhappy.
```

The file is marked with HTML tags, and I need to make the replacements only occur between the `<b>` and `</b>` tags.

```
The whale asked <b>the shark to swim</b> elsewhere.
<b>The fish were</b> unhappy.
```

This becomes:

```
The whale asked <b> the (shark) to swim </b> elsewhere.
<b> The (fish) were </b> unhappy.
```

- The matching bold tags are never place on different lines. The starting `<b>` tag always appears on the same line as the ending `</b>` tag.

How can I restrict `awk`'s search to only search and modify the text found between `<b>` and `</b>` tags?

Comment: read up on the `match()` function and its related awk vars, RSTART and RLENGTH. Good luck.

Comment: One UUOC award awaiting you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a technique using `awk`:

```
awk '/<b>/{f=1}/<\/b>/{f=0}f{gsub(/fish|shark|whale/,"(&)")}1' RS=' ' ORS=' ' file
The whale asked <b>the (shark) to swim</b> elsewhere.
<b>The (fish) were</b> unhappy.
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as the HTML markup isn't worse than that, and the `<b> ... </b>` spans won't contain any other HTML markup, then it is relatively easy in Perl:

```
$ cat data
The whale asked <b>the shark to swim</b> elsewhere.
<b>The fish were</b> unhappy.
The <b> dogfish and the sharkfin soup</b> were unscathed.
$ perl -pe 's/(<b>[^<]*)\b(fish|shark|whale)\b([^<]*<\/b>)/\1(\2)\3/g'  data | so
The whale asked <b>the (shark) to swim</b> elsewhere.
<b>The (fish) were</b> unhappy.
The <b> dogfish and the sharkfin soup</b> were unscathed.
$
```

I tried adapting that to `awk` (and `gawk`), and wasn't successful; the match part worked, but the substitution expressions did not.  Reading the manual, you don't have the ability to identify the separate match sub-expressions in the parentheses, unlike Perl.

Comment: Also, I note that `if <b>the shark and the whale swim</b> together`, only the shark gets parenthesized.  If that's a problem, you have to work quite a bit harder.  It can be done if necessary — exercise for the reader!